# Ajax GET for external api without CSRF checking

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, csrf

In my laravel 5.3 application I have enable CSRF checking globally for all ajax requests.

```
 $.ajaxSetup({
        headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token' : $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content') }
    });
```

But I have an ajax GET request for an external api as follows.

```
  $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.xxxxxxxxxxx/v1/" +code+ "?api_key="+API_KEY,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "text",
        success: function (data) {
        },
        error: function (msg) {
        }
    });
```

I need to avoid CSRF checking here. I have tried two ways but nothing works for me. In `VerifyCsrfToken.php`
**1st way**

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
    protected $except = [
        'https://api.xxxxxxxxx/v1/*'
    ];
}
```

**2nd way**

```
class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
        if ( ! $request->is('https://api.xxxxxxxxx/v1/*'))
        {
                return parent::handle($request, $next);
        }

            return $next($request);
```

}

Please figure it out, how to solve this issue.

Comment: Please show your route file. Did you add `api` routes in `api.php` file?

Comment: No, I didn't do any change for api.php

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I figured out a way within `javascript`. We can delete the particular header before  `ajax` call, then reassign the header again.

```
delete $.ajaxSettings.headers["X-CSRF-Token"];

    $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.xxxxxxxxxxx/v1/" +code+ "?api_key="+API_KEY,
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "text",
            success: function (data) {
            },
            error: function (msg) {
            }
        });

$.ajaxSettings.headers["X-CSRF-Token"] = $('meta[name=_token]').attr('content');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override the `ajaxSetup` in that `ajax` call like this.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.xxxxxxxxxxx/v1/" +code+ "?api_key="+API_KEY,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "text",
    headers : {},
    success: function (data) {
    },
    error: function (msg) {
    }
});
```

Although, you shouldn't use `ajaxSetup`.

> The settings specified here will affect all calls to $.ajax or Ajax-based derivatives such as $.get(). **This can cause undesirable behavior since other callers (for example, plugins) may be expecting the normal default settings.** For that reason we strongly recommend against using this API. Instead, set the options explicitly in the call or define a simple plugin to do so. : https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajaxsetup/

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Laravel documentation explains the use of ajax setup. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
$.ajax({
                type:'GET',
                url:"https://api.xxxxxxxxxxx/v1/" +code+ "?api_key="+API_KEY,
                data:{_token: "{{ csrf_token() }}", 
                },
                success: function( msg ) {

                }
            });
```